# How to remove 'view' link in reports?

Tags: civireport, links, column

Can't seem to find an answer. Exporting PDF and Print reports for event check-in sheet at the front door. Want to either remove the link or the default Last/First name column to stop the 'view' link from appearing.

Howto?

Comment: which report specifically?

Answer (score 1):

To address this in the browser view, you should be able to target those links with a CSS selector.

Eg, for this report on the demo site -

- http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/search?reset=1&force=1&status=true&event=1

you can hide the View/Edit/Delete links by targetting `.action-item`. You'll need to restrict this CSS to the report in question, so you might want to look at [using `.extra.tpl` to achieve this](https://civicrm.org/blog/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates).

You can also directly do this in the browser console before printing.

```
CRM.$('.action-item').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do what youre talking about will be to alter your CRM/Report/Form/Event/*report you are using*.php file.

The alterDisplay function is formatting the display name as links by default.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Find Participants" report, are you aware that the "Print " view will make a print format version for you? Try this via the event "Find Participants" view (eg [here on demo](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/search?reset=1&force=1&status=true&event=1)).

[image: print selected rows action]

[image: print output]